# Error when validate XML complextype imported ORACLE

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd

**I have 2 schemas:**

In a schema (schema_2) I define some types that I will use in the other schema (schema_1). The problem is that when I validate, when inserted into a table defined as the type of schema_1, it does not detect the nodes that are inside a complex type that I imported from schema_2.

**Schema_2:**

```
begin
begin 
 dbms_xmlschema.deleteschema(schemaURL => 'schema_2.xsd',
   delete_option => dbms_xmlschema.delete_cascade_force);
exception
when others then 
 null;
end;
 DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA(SCHEMAURL=>'schema_2.xsd', 
 SCHEMADOC=>'<xsd:schema xmlns:pty="schema_2.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="schema_2.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
<!-- 

    prueba de PresentationBody

 -->
<xsd:complexType name="Complex_1">
<xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="ReportingFI">
   </xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:simpleType name="Simple_Type">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Receipt version</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:enumeration value="2.0"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:element name="Element_type">
</xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>', LOCAL=>true, GENTYPES=>false, GENBEAN=>false, GENTABLES=>false, 
    FORCE=>false, OPTIONS=>DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTER_BINARYXML, OWNER=>USER);
 commit;
end;
```

**Schema_1 (imports from Schema_2):**

```
begin
begin 
 dbms_xmlschema.deleteschema(schemaURL => 'schema_1.xsd',
   delete_option => dbms_xmlschema.delete_cascade_force);
exception
when others then 
 null;
end;
 DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA(SCHEMAURL=>'schema_1.xsd', 
 SCHEMADOC=>'<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pty="schema_2.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.0">
    <xsd:import namespace="schema_2.xsd" schemaLocation="schema_2.xsd"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="NT_Test">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="PresentationHeader">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="PresentationCode" type="xsd:string">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="es">
                  Identificador único del mensaje generado por el declarante
                </xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="PresentationBody_2" type="pty:Simple_Type"/>
      <xsd:element name="PresentationBody_3" type="pty:Complex_1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="Presentation" type="NT_Test"/>


</xsd:schema>', LOCAL=>true, GENTYPES=>false, GENBEAN=>false, GENTABLES=>false, 
    FORCE=>false, OPTIONS=>DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTER_BINARYXML, OWNER=>USER);
 commit;
end;
```

**I create a table:**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_XML(id number,test_pres xmltype)
XMLTYPE COLUMN test_pres
STORE AS BINARY XML
XMLSCHEMA "schema_1.xsd"
ELEMENT "Presentation";
```

**When I insert an XML register, I have an error:**

```
declare
test_clob clob;

begin 
test_clob := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <Presentation> 
              <PresentationHeader>
                <PresentationCode>
                29020160000000000001
                </PresentationCode>
             </PresentationHeader>
             <PresentationBody_2>2.0</PresentationBody_2>
             <PresentationBody_3>
                 <ReportingFI>
                </ReportingFI>
             </PresentationBody_3>
          </Presentation>';

insert into TEST_XML values(1,xmltype(test_clob));

end;
```

**Error:**

```
Error report -
ORA-31061: XDB error: XML event error
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LSX-00213: only 0 occurrences of particle "ReportingFI", minimum is 1
ORA-06512: at line 19
31061. 00000 -  "XDB error: %s"
*Cause:    The specified error occurred in XDB.
*Action:   Correct the error or contact Oracle Support Services.
```

**Why dooesn't find ReportingFI particle if I insert it??**

Comment: there's nothing between `<ReportingFI>` and `</ReportingFI>` tags. Is it normal?

Comment: The tag <ReportingFI> has not restricted... it can be null. I have the same error if I insert: <ReportingFI>notnull</ReportingFI>